# Добавление HTTPS на домен и поддомены

Tags: https, letsencrypt

Сертификат от Letsencrypt. Ситуация такая есть домен site.ru. Возможно ли добавить алиас домена к примеру вот так *.site.ru чтоб все поддомены этого домена работали по https. Поддоменов имею много, и часто добавляются новые. Можно ли это реализовать один раз командой? или нужно каждый раз обновлять https?
К примеру как работает ucoz.

Comment: https://letsencrypt.org/2017/07/06/wildcard-certificates-coming-jan-2018.html

Comment: Ага тоже уже на гуглил, а незнаешь ли бесплатные хорошие Wildcard SSL?

Comment: Во-первых, эти два требования противоречат друг другу, во-вторых, кроме letsencrypt нет

Comment: Cloudflare предоставляет бесплатные wildcard сертификаты сразу на 15 лет. Правда, ns домена при этом должен быть cloudflare.